# Why does this code not work as intended?

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm writing a simple method that takes grades as input from the user and calculates the Grade Point Average. Here is my code:

```
public static double calculateGPA(){
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

   double totalGradePoints = 0; // total grade points
   int numClasses = 0; // total classes completed
   boolean doneInput = false; // returns true when use is done inputting grades

   System.out.println("Enter all your grades (A,B,C,D,F) and enter 'done' if you are done entering your grades.");  
   while (!doneInput) {     
      String grade = in.next();

      if (grade == "A") {
         totalGradePoints += 4;
         numClasses++;
      } else if (grade == "B") {
         totalGradePoints += 3;
         numClasses++;
      } else if(grade == "C") {
         totalGradePoints += 2;
         numClasses++;
      } else if(grade == "D") {
         totalGradePoints += 1;
         numClasses++;
      } else if(grade == "F") {
         numClasses++;
      } else {
         doneInput = true;
      } //end if - else-if - else statement
   }//end while loop
   double unwtGPA = (totalGradePoints/numClasses);
   return unwtGPA;
}
```

When I tested the method, I was only able to input one grade and none of the variables incremented, can somebody tell me what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 11):

The issue is with the string comparison using `==` instead of `equals`. `==` compares the references, which are very unlikely to be equal. Change to

```
 if(grade.equals("A")){
        totalGradePoints += 4;
        numClasses++;
    }else if(grade.equals("B")){ ...
```

and it should work. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion) for a detailed explanation.

As a good practice it is advisable to always use the static string as the object for calling equals on to prevent a NPE:

```
 if("A".equals(grade)){
        totalGradePoints += 4;
        numClasses++;
    }else if("B".equals(grade)){ ...
```

If you are using Java 7, you can also do a `switch` statement with strings (though this one will throw an NPE if grade is null):

```
switch(grade) {
    case "A":
        totalGradePoints += 2;
        numClasses++;
        break;
    case "B":
        ...
}
```

And finally, since you are converting only one letter to an integer, to best solution is to convert them to char and for the values between `A` and `D` to do `totalGradePoints += ('D' - grade.charAt(1)) + 1`. So something along those lines would be simplest to read IMO:

```
while (true) {        
    final String input = in.next();
    if(input == null || input.isEmpty())
        break;

    final char grade = input.charAt(0);
    if(grade >= 'A' && grade <= 'D') {
        totalGradePoints += ('D' - grade) + 1;
    } else if(grade == 'F') {
        // no gradepoints for 'F'
    } else {
        break;
    } //end if - else-if - else statement

    ++numClasses;
} //end while loop
```

Comment: or, even better, to a `switch`.

Comment: Maybe operator overloading works?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik not in Java it doesn't.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Yes, switch would be better, but only available since Java 7 I think.

Comment: What is the JVM actually doing when it compares the references as opposed to using the equals()?

Comment: @user3189506: Compare memory addresses where the corresponding objects are located.

Comment: And for those who downvoted: Care to elaborate why?

Comment: The only thing i would add is `"A".equals(grade)` to avoid NPE-s. Maybe it's not relevant here but a good practice. Still upvoted for the java 7 switch :)

Comment: I don't know who downvoted but I would if the `switch` statement was missing.

Comment: Better to use a Map than a switch

Comment: @bali182: I was writing it that why, which I use as common practice, but decided against to not confuse the readability. Will make a mention of that. Furthermore, the switch is not safe neither.

Comment: @JanickBernet pre Java 7 you could use a `switch` on `char` which would work fine because the OP only needs one letter.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Agreed, but then I would use third option I suggested.

Comment: I think `gradeC` is a confusing name; better to call it `gradeChar`? Also, can you remove the duplication of `numClasses++`?

Comment: @aetheria: I changed `gradeC` to `grade`, since that's the one we care about in the code, and renamed the string to `gradeStr`. I removed the duplication of `numClassess++`, but I'm not sure it's now a bit less easy to grasp when it's executed.

Comment: I find this method too unobvious - the calculation of `'D' - grade + 1` requires hard thinking to know it's right. Also, if you enter a string like 'DONE', won't it add a 'D' to your GPA?

Comment: I would rename the variable `gradeStr` as `input` or `inputStr`, because it is not always a grade, sometimes it might be a blank line or the word 'done' or a mistake. You could change the calculation to `'E' - grade` to avoid the `+ 1` bit. I still think it's unobvious code that relies on a certain relationship, which may not always hold going forwards, e.g. if A is worth 5 points in some places.

Comment: Renamed to input. The `+ 1` I did intentionally, I find it more readable like this, but that's a matter of preference. And I agree that the whole thing is very tailored towards the given scale, but I think that's good enough.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that the `+ 1` might be more obvious. Minor things: You don't need the null check for input. And what about if they write `DONE`, won't it give them a `D`? Maybe you could check that the length of the input is 1?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using `==` to compare Strings, when you should be using `s.equals("...")`. The `==` operator checks identity and Strings are not guaranteed to have the same identity (there may be several objects representing exactly the same string). The `equals()` method compares the *contents* of the Strings for equality rather than the identity of the objects.

I would write it more like this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

double totalGradePoints = 0; // total grade points
int numClasses = 0; // total classes completed

System.out.println("Enter all your grades (A,B,C,D,F) and"
        + " write 'done' when you have finished");

while (true) {
    String input = in.next();
    if (input.equals("done")) {
        break;
    }
    if (input.equals("A")) {
        totalGradePoints += 4;
    } else if (input.equals("B")) {
        totalGradePoints += 3;
    } else if (input.equals("C")) {
        totalGradePoints += 2;
    } else if (input.equals("D")) {
        totalGradePoints += 1;
    } else if (!input.equals("F")) {
        System.err.println("Invalid input: " + input);
        continue;
    }
    numClasses++;
}
double unweightedGPA = (totalGradePoints / numClasses);
System.out.println(unweightedGPA);
```

The `while(true)` loop with `break` (to exit the loop) and `continue` (to skip back to the start of the loop) is more idiomatic Java. The main benefit with my version above is that there is no duplication of the line `numClasses++`.

You could even make the loop more succinct and make it simpler to alter the grade points by using a Map, which will return a points value for the grade or `null` for an invalid grade:

```
Map<String, Integer> gradePoints = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
    put("A", 4);
    put("B", 3);
    put("C", 2);
    put("D", 1);
    put("F", 0);
}};

String input;
while (!(input = in.next()).equals("done")) {
    Integer points = gradePoints.get(input);
    if (points == null) {
        System.err.println("Invalid input: " + input);
        continue;
    }
    totalGradePoints += points;
    numClasses++;
}
```

It's also worth pointing out that in your code and in all the answers on this page, if you don't enter any grades, you will get a division-by-zero (yielding NaN), so you might want to think about handling that gracefully.

Comment: I am no java expert but how does a map behave if one passes in keys that are not in the map.

Comment: The map returns `null` if it can't find the key. Hence the line `if (points == null)...`

Comment: thank you for the clarification - I think you should mention this *in* the answer, nevertheless an elegant solution +1

Comment: Thanks. I've explained that part more.

Answer (score 0):

Your failure is to use the `==` operator to check Strings on equality. Strings are objects so in this case there will be a check on object identity (which defaults to a reference check).

Use `equals` to make a character by character check like so:

```
if(grade.equals("A")){
```